# Is the sentence "you just look like the people that it's never their fault" right?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I want to write an informal sentence to ironically tell someone it is never their fault just because they look innocent. Does the following sentence sound right?

`You just look like the people that it's never their fault.`

Is there a way to build a sentence with "whose" in this case?

`You just look like the people ... whose fault ...`

Comment: Your sentence makes no sense. You seem to be trying to say:**You look like the kind of person who relies on their innocent looks to escape blame.** There are lots of ways to express this but not the way you have chosen. You need to rethink it.

Comment: I think the version with **whose** is in fact the only way to properly make the sentence.  Firstly, it should always be *who* or *whose*, not *that*, because these are people, not objects.  Also, *it's never their fault* doesn't fit after *the people who*; the noun phrase starts with "the people", so that's the head of the NP, but *who* needs a relative clause, and "it's never their fault" isn't one; you don't put a new subject like "it" in a relative clause.